# Change ansible output

Tags: linux, text, formatting, ansible, output

I have some tasks with loops and when I run them I get something like this in output:

```
TASK [mytask : Create files] **********************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=(censored due to no_log))
changed: [localhost] => (item=(censored due to no_log))
changed: [localhost] => (item=(censored due to no_log))
```

Is there a way to change it to

```
TASK [mytask : Create files] **********************************************
changed: [localhost] => (create file1)
changed: [localhost] => (create file2)
changed: [localhost] => (create file3)
```

without external utils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [loop_control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control):

```
- name: create files
  file: 
    path: "/tmp/tmp_{{ item }}"
    state: touch
  with_items: [1,2,3]
  loop_control:
    label: "create file {{ item }}"
```